# Cholesky decomposition for sparse matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, block-matrices, cholesky-decomposition

I have a symmetric positive definite matrix that is composed of small block diagonal matrices. For example:

$$
M = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
\Sigma & \Psi & \Psi \\
\Psi   & \Sigma & \Psi \\
\Psi   & \Psi   & \Sigma \\
\end{array}
\right],
$$
where both $\Sigma$ and $\Psi$ are diagonal matrices.

My question is: Is there an efficient way to perform Cholesky decomposition on this? It is such a regular matrix, that I feel like one must be able to do some trick to simplify the problem, rather than use brute force method.

For 2x2, I found a simple solution shown [Block LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_LU_decomposition). However, I couldn't figure out how to generalize this to n dimension.

Thanks for your help.

Bin

Comment: I presume it is symmetric positive definite?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:** Try to come up with a general diagonalization method for a matrix of this form. Because both matrices $\Sigma$ and $\Psi$ are diagonal themselves, you can assume they're scalar for this purpose. For example, using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InverseMatrix%5B%7B%7Ba,b,b%7D,%7Bb,a,b%7D,%7Bb,b,a%7D%7D%5D), we can get a diagonal matrix $D$ composed by:

$$
D = S^{-1}MS
$$

With:
$$
S = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & -1 & 1 \\
 0 &  1 & 1 \\
 1 &  0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Then, $D^{-1}$ would be straightforward to compute. Note you need to replace the ones with the identity matrix.

As another example, computed with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InverseMatrix%5B%7B%7Ba,b,b,b%7D,%7Bb,a,b,b%7D,%7Bb,b,a,b%7D,%7Bb,b,b,a%7D%7D%5D), for a 4th order $M$ matrix, $S$ would be:

$$
S = \left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
-1 & -1 & -1 & 1 \\
 0 &  0 &  1 & 1 \\
 0 &  1 &  0 & 1 \\
 1 &  0 &  0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$